# How To Inspect Blazor Wasm Services Class Data in VS Community 2019 Debugger

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, visual-studio-debugging

I have a small Blazor Wasm app in VS Community 2019 that I am using to learn how it all works.  I have setup some Services Singleton data classes to share data across Blazor components.  The problem is that I can't see any of the data in the debugger, either via mouse-over in the code or by entering statements in the VS Immediate Window when stopped at a break point.  If I assign the Services data to local variables in my code, I am able to see it in those variables using the debugger, so I know it is in the Services Singleton.

I am hoping that I'm doing something wrong, versus there's simply no way to see Services data in the debugger.  Thanks for any guidance.  Steve

Comment: Did you use Angular service? Besides, share a minimal, reproducible sample with us so that we can troubleshoot your issue more quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How To Inspect Blazor Wasm Services Class Data in VS Community 2019
> Debugger

**Actually**, you cannot get the service data directly in Blazor project in debugger.

To obtain the service data, you need to convert this service data into the project and receive it with local variables in order to debug their values.

**Besides**, if you still want to see service data in vs debugger, you could suggest a feature request on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and I hope the team will give you a satisfactory reply.